# Patent on public domain information? I covered this patent in my books

Tags: tree, chair, treeshaping

https://patents.google.com/patent/CN106577131A/en?q=(method+for+quickly+growing+arborsculpture+by+grafting+large+branches+togther)&oq=method+for+quickly+growing+arborsculpture+by+grafting+large+branches+togther++

My books are "How to grow a chair" 1995 Reames-Dlebol and Arborsculpture solution for a small planet 2005 I cover this chinese patente that was recently granted. I thought I put the information into the public domain. Is the patent good?

Comment: Do they use the same steps to accomplish making a chair ?

Comment: Once issued, validity of a patent is usually claim by claim. It depends on a careful comparison of the features of each claim with what is taught by the prior art (which would normally include published books) and is usually at least partly a subjective process. It may well be valid if not all features are as described in the prior art, or if the combination is considered sufficiently new (approximately). If the existence of this patent is hampering you in some way, you might look into the possibility of challenging it though a patent attorney in China.

Comment: @bhuff36 Your comment would make an adequate answer with a bit of editing. I encourage you to post it as such.

Comment: @EricS I don't think my "answer" really gets to the heart of the matter. Ideally this question should catch the interest of someone who knows Chinese and can truly shed some light on what is being claimed and whether the books are relevant prior art.

Comment: @bhuff36 Unfortunately, such a person probably doesn't exist here on Ask Patents. Any answer you provide doesn't preclude a better answer from someone else. In any case, I will post an answer inspired by your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to your books and don't know Chinese so I can only rely on Google's translation of the Chinese Patent's text. What I can say is that your books predate the filing of the patent so thus represent potential prior art. People often over estimate the extent of a patent. The claims define what is protected. Long, complicated claims are generally fairly narrow since one would have to implement each and every step in the claim to infringe. Claim one of the cited patent (quoted below) is exceptionally long with eight fairly extensive steps. All the other claims are dependent on claim 1 so someone would have to infringe on claim 1 to infringe the patent.

Again, I do not have access to your books, but anything you describe in them likely became unpatentable after their publication. A specific refinement to what you describe could potentially be patentable. In any case, I believe the patent doesn't attempt to patent chairs formed by shaping trees in general. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaping) cites several examples that well predate even your books.

> 1. a kind of preparation method with crown umbrella tree chair, it is characterised in that：The chair leg of the tree chair is made up of
>    four trees trunk, The planting location of four trees is in
>    quadrangle, and during making, prefabricated seat mould, bracing
>    frame, the tree chair preparation method with tree crown includes
>    Following steps： 1), connected using rope in four chair leg height and
>    positions, prefabricated seat mould is set thereon； 2), in four chair
>    leg trees, each trunk in chair leg height and position, stay
>    respectively two tree buds, tree bud present position towards On the
>    direction of adjacent chair leg, tree bud grows in opposite directions
>    in the horizontal direction of four legs； 3), leave two tree bud each
>    chair leg trunk eye top 0.2-3cm place distinguish partial application,
>    cutting-in to xylem, Promote to set bud and sprout, homing tree bud is
>    allowed between trunk to along horizontal direction to two anyhow
>    adjacent trunk directions growths Interconnect, constitute
>    fore-and-aft direction chair leg connection strap and left and right
>    directions chair leg connection strap； 4) multiple Propagating Tree
>    buds backward or upwards, are reserved respectively at a certain
>    distance on left and right directions chair leg connection strap,
>    wherein, Bud is set before tree chair on left and right directions
>    chair leg connection strap to grow backward, base connection strip is
>    formed, behind the connection of left and right directions chair leg
>    Upper tree bud grows up, and forms backrest connection strap, and a
>    deep knife at above-mentioned multiple eye top 0.2-3cm, up to xylem,
>    makes Tree bud growth； 5), set four legs of chair respectively in
>    chair leg height and position to front curve horizontal by 30-60 ° of
>    angle, the is formed respectively One bend, at the first bend 10-30cm,
>    respectively before and after the left and right sides leg formed
>    plane in, then backward bending with Horizontal plane forms
>    respectively the bend of left and right sides second in 30-60 ° of
>    angle, makes the second bend of the left and right sides along seat
>    mould Top edge rearward grows, and forms arcuation tree chair top
>    edge, and tree chair top edge crosses in chair back side centre
>    position； 6) tree bud is stayed at a certain distance on the
>    fore-and-aft direction chair leg connection strap for, setting chair,
>    deep one at the 0.2-3cm of eye top Knife, depth reaches xylem,
>    meanwhile, in both sides second, bend arranges downward extension
>    branch by identical spacing number, forms upper and lower Direction
>    connection strap, meets position respectively in left and right sides
>    connection strap above-below direction, by meet both be whittled into
>    relative wedge shape, and Binding, becomes the two and combines
>    together； 7), above-mentioned steps 5）Tree chair top edge makes branch
>    mutually wind after chair back side centre position is intersecting,
>    carries out at by branch Reason so as to bend to vertically upward and
>    vertical-growth, form vertical trunk, at vertical trunk height is for
>    1.5m-2m, then It is secondary to carry out by branch process so as to bend forwards, form tree crown, when forming tree crown, bracing frame
>    is supported on into lower section, allow tree crown to give birth to
>    It is long, corrected accordingly and pruned according to shape of
>    tree-crown； 8）, tree chair formed after remove seat mould, after tree
>    crown is formed, remove bracing frame.